# How to see if each letter in a variable is in a set

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to see if EACH letter in a variable is in a set. However when trying to do this my program does not run as expected.

This is the code:

```
guess = "abcd"

alphabet = ('a', 'b', 'd')

for letter in guess:
    if letter in guess in alphabet:
        print("That letter is  in the alphabet")
    elif letter in guess not in alphabet:
        print("That letter is not in the alphabet
```

However the code just returns this:

```
That letter is not in the alphabet
That letter is not in the alphabet
That letter is not in the alphabet
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear whether you're looking for a password that is formed with a k-permutation of letters from your set , or if you want the computer to guess the letters in the set .

Given the first scenario, you want your program to brute force a password by iterating over all k-permutations of possible passwords made from letters from .  is the maximum length of the password (e.g. 2, 4, ..., 32, ...).

Comment: Well to be more specific:

Comment: I want the program to check EACH letter of the string given to the computer and try to match it up until it finds a match in the set. Or I can use ord() actually and match ord values. But what I'm asking is how to match a letter (string) with another string in the set and iterate that until a match succeeds

Comment: If your just looking to check whether a letter is in a set, here <letters>, use the reserved keyword <in> as in: ```if letter in letters:```